# Customizing android home screen icons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

How can I change the default icons in homescreen as done by the applications mentioned [here](http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/customization/complete-guide-to-customizing-your-home-screen-icons/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your application's icon then find in `AndroidManifest.xml` this:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

put your icon in `res/drawable` directory of project and write its name in place of `ic_launcher`